# UITableView Cell Insert Row Glitch

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view with custom cells (all configured in a subclass using auto layout).

The cells load fine, display fine, everything is fine.

**The issue** is when I am inserting more rows (at the bottom). The table view is representing a feed for posts, so when the user scrolls to the bottom, before reaching the last cell, I load new posts, and then insert them into the table.

When I do this, I get this weird glitchy effect where the cells randomly come down (behind the previous cells) into place, the table view scrolls up a bit, messy.

#### CODE AT BOTTOM

I've uploaded a clip of me scrolling. When you see the activity indicator, 
I stop scrolling. The rest of the movement is from the glitchy behavior.

[image]

---

- Is the reason for the glitch because the cells are being drawn with auto-layout?

I would hope not, but idk..I'm not sure what to do regarding a solution. If anyone has any ideas please let me know.

**FYI:**

I have this (of course, since the cells are all using auto layout)

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

I've tried setting the estimated height to an "average" of the expected cell heights, around 65. No difference.

### Update

Here's some code:

**HomeViewController.m** --> viewDidLoad

```
...
self.tableView = [KATableView.alloc initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.refreshDelegate = self;

self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 75;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

// Constrains to all 4 sides of self.view
[SSLayerEffects constrainView:self.tableView toAllSidesOfView:self.view];
```

**my table view data source**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (!self.dataManager.didFinishFetchingData) return 4;
    if (self.contentObjects.count == 0) return 1;
    if (self.dataManager.moreToLoad) return self.contentObjects.count + 1;
    return self.contentObjects.count + 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MYObject *object = self.contentObjects[indexPath.row];
    SomeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:object.documentID];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [SomeTableViewCell.alloc initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:object.documentID];
            cell.delegate = self;
    } else [cell startListeningForChanges];


    return cell;

}
```

Here is how I am loading more data and adding it to the table view..

```
- (void)getHomeFeedData:(nullable void(^)(BOOL finished))completed {

    [self.dataManager fetchHomeFeedDataForFeedOption:self.homeNavController.feedFilterOption completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error, NSArray<__kindof KAObject *> * _Nullable feedObjects) {

        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"something went wrong: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            if (completed) completed(NO);
            return;
        }

        NSInteger originalCount = self.contentObjects.count;

        if (self.dataManager.isFirstTimeLoading) self.contentObjects = feedObjects.mutableCopy;
        else {
            if (self.dataManager.isGettingNew) for (MYObject *obj in feedObjects) [self.contentObjects insertObject:obj atIndex:0];
            else if (feedObjects.count > 0) [self.contentObjects addObjectsFromArray:feedObjects];
        }


        if (feedObjects.count > 0) {
            if (self.dataManager.isFirstTimeLoading) [self.tableView reloadData];
            else {
                [self.tableView insertCells:feedObjects forSection:0 startingIndex:self.dataManager.isGettingNew? 0 : originalCount];
            }
        } else if (self.dataManager.isFirstTimeLoading) [self.tableView reloadData];


        if (completed) completed(YES);

    }];

}
```

**NOTE:**

> ```
> [self.tableView insertCells:feedObjects forSection:0 startingIndex:self.dataManager.isGettingNew? 0 : originalCount];
> ```

is simply this:

```
- (void)insertCells:(nullable NSArray *)cells forSection:(NSInteger)section startingIndex:(NSInteger)start {

    if (!cells) return;

    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = @[].mutableCopy;

    for (id obj in cells) {
        NSInteger index = [cells indexOfObject:obj] + start;
        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:section]];
    }

    [self insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

}
```

### Update 2

My `UITableViewCell` subclass content is hidden ATM (too much difficulty in editing all my post content for the purpose of this post). I just have the subviews of each cell set to `alpha = 0.f`. It's just an image view, some labels, and some buttons.

**No constraint issues in console**, cells render perfectly when calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` so maybe there is something I'm doing wrong when inserting the cells?...

Comment: after inserting cells in table view....are you calling reloadData() method of tableview?

Comment: No I just call insertRowsAt... bla bla don’t want to reload the whole table view

Comment: post some code so people can help you

Comment: @WillVonUllrich I would kindly ask you to reconsider the wording of "too lazy to edit all my post content for the purpose of this post" - this shades with arrogance and does not encourage people to be dedicated while creating an answer for you.

Comment: @MahendraGP Lol fair point - changed

Answer (score 1):

When you dealing with `UITableView` glitches:

1. Make sure you call UIKit API's on a main thread - turn on Main Thread checker

[image]

In your case, there might be an issue that `fetchHomeFeedDataForFeedOption:completion:` completion block is called not on a main thread.

2. Your insert is definitely wrong - all delete/insert/update/move calls for `UITableView` should be wrapped in `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates`
3. Your "load more" component at the bottom might be an issue. You need to address how it's managing contentSize/contentOffset/contentInset of table view. If it does anything but manipulating contentInset - it does wrong job.

While it's hard without debugging the whole solution, I bet options 2 & 3 are the key problems out there.

Comment: Thanks for the help Petro - appreciate it. Figured it could be a thread issue - I threw the updates on the main thread and experienced the same issues, but I *am* aware of using begin/end updates, just not using that. Probably should try that - I haven't yet.

Comment: it looks like the issue is often when cells are being inserted while you are scrolling OR are holding the table passed the last cell. When this is done statically no issue.

Comment: I figured it out - just had to set up some monitors keeping an eye on optimal times to insert the cells. Ugly - wish inserting cells could be done whenever...